# Determine if a method is 'extern' using reflection

Tags: c#, reflection

How do I determine if a method is `extern` , using reflection?

Sample method:

```
var mEnter = typeof(System.Threading.Monitor).GetMethod("Exit", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);
```

Comment: Take a look at the [`MethodImplAttributes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodimplattributes.aspx) enum at `MethodInfo.MethodImplementationFlags`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
var isExtern = (mEnter.MethodImplementationFlags
                    & MethodImplAttributes.InternalCall) != 0;
```

Comment: It works fine for this method but not for Threading.Interlocked public static extern object CompareExchange(ref object location1, object value, object comparand);

I'll update my question

Comment: @animaonline works fine for that too: `var method = typeof(System.Threading.Interlocked).GetMethod("CompareExchange", new[] { typeof(object).MakeByRefType(), typeof(object), typeof(object) });`

Comment: If you're using `DllImportAttribute` then the method will be marked with `PreserveSig`.

Comment: But of course! That method was generic and was not marked as extern :)  Thank you for your answer!

Comment: @animaonline indeed, there's a generic version too, which is *not* `extern`

Answer (score 4):

I don't know is any direct way to figure out but I can show a trick
that I used.

Suppose we have a class that contains an `extern` method, e.g.:

```
class MyClass
{
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    public static extern bool Beep(int ferequency, int duration);
    public static void gr()
    {
    }
    public void GG()
    {
    }
}
```

we can get detect extern methods with this code:

```
var t = typeof(MyClass);
var l = t.GetMethods();
foreach (var item in l)
{
    if (item.GetMethodBody() == null && item.IsStatic)
    {
        // Method is Extern
    }
}
```