# Where are managed/native transitions in the StackTrace?

Tags: .net, stack-trace

In .NET applications, you can fetch the stack trace from an `Exception` object. I'm looking for the managed to native transitions (and other direction) in that stack trace. The Visual Studio debugger can show these special frames, but in the code, I see something else. There are frames without a managed IL offset (from the `GetILOffset()` method), but with modules and method names that Visual Studio doesn't see. Where do they come from, and how can I interpret them?

The following screenshot shows an example of such a stack trace in my application. Yellow highlighted are the methods where Visual Studio indicates native methods. The Metadata token "+number" is the managed IL code offset. Where is none, I suspect it's a native method.

[image]

This is what Visual Studio shows for the same spot:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are seeing two different views of the stack trace, otherwise without any way to make them the same.  It is the native code stack frames that disturb the view, reliably walking native code frames requires debugging information, the kind that requires a PDB file, only a native debugger has a shot at it.

The top view is generated by a StackTrace object.  It completely skips native stack frames.  The ones you highlighted are in fact C# methods, they have the `extern` attribute.  Respectively for `[DllImport]` declarations (pinvoke) and `[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall)]` (code that lives inside the CLR and the jitter knows about).  There is no IL for them so getting 0 from GetILOffset() is expected.  That however doesn't mean that a 0 is a reliable indication, you'd have to find the attribute back to filter them.

The debugger's Call Stack window intentionally hides these methods.  The debugger cannot display anything meaningful for them, nothing to show in the Autos and Locals window.  You'd have to enable unmanaged debugging to see more.

The [transition] annotations in the debugger view are generated from jitter metadata, info that's only available through the debugger interface and not considered by the StackTrace class.  Generated from the links between managed stack frames, metadata that the GC needs to reliably walk stack frames without the risk of blundering into unmanaged stack frames and mis-interpret native pointer values as object references.  This is otherwise what it means to transition from managed to native code and back, the cost is maintaining those links.  It is very cheap.

Comment: The `DispatchMessage` method is `[DllImport] extern`. It's interesting that it appears two times consecutively in the stack trace. Can an external method call itself in a managed way? Or is the stack trace wrong? For my diagnostics case, it might already be enough to know whether the method in the frame is external. http://stackoverflow.com/q/19768407/143684 should help me there although I've hoped for a simple `IsExtern` property...